# How to use Jackson to deserialise a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am passing a 2D array JSON to a spring controller, but getting jackson error.

```
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 
    Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token
```

My javascript 2D array looks like this.

```
[ ["John", "Doe", "worker", "fulltime"], 
  ["Adam", "Smith", "nonworker", "temp"],
  ["Jane", "Doe", "worker", "fulltime"] ]
```

The bean class it gets mapped to 2D array like this.

```
public class MyBean implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3948256457L;


    String[][] workInfo = null;


    public String[][] getWorkInfo() {
        return workInfo;
    }


    public void setWorkInfo(String[][] workInfo) {
        this.workInfo = workInfo;
    }           

}
```

In the spring controller, I am using something like this.

```
    public ModelAndView addData(@RequestBody MyBean tempForm) throws Exception{

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(new org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView());

    try{
        myService.addData(tempForm);

        model.addObject("mesage", "success");   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {           
        model.addObject("mesage", "error");
        log.error("error:"+e);
    }

    }
```

Can anyone suggest how can i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by inspecting the json object of my 2D arrays. It turns it was a mix of 1D array with other values. While  on the form bean end it was expecting a 2D array and jackson thought it's 1D array but couldn't translate it.

ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(new org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView());

Does the translation, so for most cases you don't need to add jackson annotation in your form bean class if Object being sent it similar on both sides e.g. In my case i was sending a javascript 2D array and in my form bean i had defined a 2D array. Also make sure there's a form tag in you jsp or other page etc.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your array is a rectangular size?

You should be able to do this with a list:

```
List<List<String>> workInfo;
```

And then convert to a `String[][]` if you want.

You can do:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.canSerialize(MyBean.class);
```

To test that it can serialize correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try that and will let you know.